# Visual studio 2019 parsing cmake forever when changing configuration

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

Im building a c++ project using cmake (manually maintained).
I have two configurations: Windows debug 64 and Linux-GCC-Debug
VS is parsing cmake forever when I try to switch between them
Restarting VS solves the problem but its not a reasonable solution
What can be the cause ?
Tnx

Comment: *"I have two configurations: Windows debug 64 and Linux-GCC-Debug"* How? CMake restricts itself to one compiler per build system setup, and I don't know any compiler covering both Windows and Linux.

Comment: In the CMAKE you can define several configuration. for example if want to compile in windows I use if(MSVC) , which is set by the configuration (in CMakeSettings.json)